# VHDL writing warning

Tags: vhdl

1.8-bit multiplier

```html
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity M8 is
    Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
           M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
           Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(15 downto 0)
     );
end M8;
architecture Behavioral of M8 is

begin
process(M1,M2)

variable A1: std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);

begin
A1(17 downto 0) := "0000000000" & M1(7 downto 0);

for N in 1 to 9 loop
if A1(0)='1' then
A1(17 downto 9) := A1(17 downto 9) + '0'+ M2(7 downto 0);
end if;
A1(17 downto 0) := '0' & A1(17 downto 1);
end loop;
Mout<= A1(15 downto 0);
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

2.32-bit multiplier

```html
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity M32 is
    Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
           M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
           Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(63 downto 0)
     );
end M32;

architecture Behavioral of M32 is

begin
process(M1,M2)

variable A1: std_logic_vector(65 downto 0);

begin
A1(65 downto 0) := "0000000000000000000000000000000000" & M1(31 downto 0);


for N in 1 to 33 loop
if A1(0)='1' then
A1(65 downto 33) := A1(65 downto 33) + '0'+ M2(31 downto 0);
end if;
A1(65 downto 0) := '0' & A1(65 downto 1);
end loop;
Mout<= A1(63 downto 0);
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

```html
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity MM32All is

port( MMM1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      MMM2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  MMMout: out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
  );

end MM32All;

architecture Behavioral of MM32All is

component M32 port(MM1 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     MM2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   MMout:out std_logic_vector(39 downto 0)
   );
   end component;

signal MMb:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);   
signal MMa: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal MMo1:  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal MMo2:  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal MMo3:  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal MMo4:  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal MMout1: std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin
Ma4: M32 port map (MM1=> MMb, MM2=> MMa(31 downto 24), MMout=> MMo4);
Ma3: M32 port map (MM1=> MMb, MM2=> MMa(23 downto 16), MMout=> MMo3);
Ma2: M32 port map (MM1=> MMb, MM2=> MMa(15 downto 8) , MMout=> MMo2);
Ma1: M32 port map (MM1=> MMb, MM2=> MMa(7 downto 0 ) , MMout=> MMo1);

MMout1 <= ("000000000000000000000000" & MMo1) + ("0000000000000000" & MMo2 & "00000000")
+ ("00000000" & MMo3 & "0000000000000000" ) + ( MMo4 & "000000000000000000000000" );

MMb <= MMM1;
MMa <= MMM2;
MMMout <= MMout1;
end Behavioral;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity M32 is
port(MM1 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     MM2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   MMout:out std_logic_vector(39 downto 0)
   );
   
end M32;

architecture Behavioral of M32 is

component M8 Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(15 downto 0)
             );
       end component;
component M8b Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(15 downto 0)
             );
       end component;
component M8c Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(15 downto 0)
             );
                   end component;
component M8d Port ( M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
                    Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(15 downto 0)
             );
                   end component;       
signal internalMM1: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal internalMM2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal internalMMout: std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
signal M8dout:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal M8cout:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal M8bout:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal M8out:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin

--addres: for N in 0 to 3 generate
FulMd32: M8d port map( M1=> internalMM1(31 downto 24), M2=> internalMM2, Mout=> M8dout);
FulMb32: M8b port map( M1=> internalMM1(23 downto 16), M2=> internalMM2, Mout=> M8cout);
FulMc32: M8c port map( M1=> internalMM1(15 downto 8),  M2=> internalMM2, Mout=> M8bout);
FulM32:  M8 port map( M1=> internalMM1(7 downto 0),   M2=> internalMM2, Mout=> M8out);

internalMMout<=("000000000000000000000000" & M8out) 
  + ("0000000000000000" & M8bout & "00000000") + ("00000000" & M8cout & "0000000000000000")
  + (M8dout & "000000000000000000000000");

internalMM1 <= MM1;
internalMM2 <= MM2;

MMout <= internalMMout;
end Behavioral;
```

```html
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity ALU is
port( A :in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      B :in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  SS:in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  C :out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  D :out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  La,Sm,Eq: out std_logic);
end ALU;
architecture Behavioral of ALU is
Component M32 is port (M1 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                       M2 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                       Mout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(63 downto 0));
end component;

Component SUB32 is port(A : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                        B : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                       OFL:out std_logic;
                        S : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0));
end component;

Component adder32 is Port(A : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                          B : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
                        Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
                        Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
                          S : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0));         
end component;
signal aM1,aM2,bM1,bM2,cM1,cM2,cMout,bMout : STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);
signal aMout: STD_LOGIC_vector(63 downto 0);
signal Overflow: std_logic;
              
begin
A1: M32 port map( M1=> aM1, M2=>aM2, Mout=>aMout);
A2: SUB32 port map(A=> bM1, B=> bM2, S=>bMout, OFL=>Overflow);
A3: adder32 port map(A=> cM1, B=> cM2, Cout=>open,S=>cMout,Cin=>'0');

process(SS,A,B,Overflow,aMout,bMout,CMout)
begin 
Case SS is 
When "000"=> aM1<=A;
             aM2<=B;
 C<=aMout;
When "001" => if Overflow='1' then 
              bM1<=A;
              bM2<=B;
  D<=bMout;
 else 
  D<="00000000000000000000000000000000";
  end if;
when "010" => cM1<=A;
              cM2<=B;
 D<= cMout;
when "011" =>   if (A > B) then
                  La<='1';
 Sm<='0';
 Eq<='0';
                else if (A<B) then
                 La<='0';
              Sm<='1';
                 Eq<='0';
                else
              La<='0';
              Sm<='0';
              Eq<='1';
   end if;
   end if;
  when "100" =>
      D <= (A and B);
   when "101" =>
      D <= (A or B);
   when "110" =>
      D <= (A xor B);     
When others=> C<="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
              D<="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
end case;
end process;    
end Behavioral;
```

32-bit ALU

Based on the Device utilization summary, two designs of multiplier have very similar area utilization. 32-bit multiplier by 8-bit multiplier use about 5% more logic unit than single 32-bit multiplier. The number of used route thru used for 32-bit multiplier by 8-bit multiplier is 238% of single 32-bit multiplier. Even use different design,  their performance are the same.

Comment: So what is the question? Also, if you want to write a multiplier, the simplest method is to give your operands and result type `signed`, then simply write `x <= a * b`.

Comment: Use Code Sample and not Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet for including your VHDL code. Do you have a specific question?  See the 
[Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider taking the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your warning isn' in evidence.

Answer (score 0):

You have very obscure way of doing multiplier as scary_jeff indicates. Most likely the synthesis tool gets confused about that.

Instead of

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Please have

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

and instead of

```
std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)
```

use

```
signed(n-1 downto 0);
```

Then you can just multiply with *.

Off topic, but instead of

```
D<="00000000000000000000000000000000";
```

you can use

```
D <= (others => '0');
```